# Application Data folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, backwards-compatibility, programdata

I have Windows 7 64 bit installed on my system. I have a question about "C:\ProgramData\Application Data" folder.
It is mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756982.aspx) and [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/1c3e806a-0412-4591-b94a-ac2b71074b28) that "Application Data" is a Junction point which points to C:\ProgramData. So, i would expect the following command to list the contents of the C:\ProgramData folder (my ProgramData folder has folders like McAfee, Microsoft, Adobe, etc..)..

> > cd /d "c:\ProgramData\Application Data"
>
> dir

However i do not see anything listed...However, if i were to traverse 1 more directory deeper and list the contents, then all the folders under that directory are listed...

> > cd /d "c:\ProgramData\Application Data\McAfee
>
> dir

I do not understand this behaviour. Would anyone explain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's to allow backward compatibility for programs that assume the old name but to also prevent programs recursing the tree and finding both copies.

Here's [an article about this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851567.aspx) from [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) - I thought he did it on his blog, though, so maybe there's more there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link! excellent explanation by Raymond!!

Comment: A junction that links to itself is terrible design in many ways. I don't recommend it. It can cause a lot of problems more than it solves.